# Python detect linux shutdown and run a command before shutting down

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ubuntu

Is it possible to detect and interrupt linux (Ubuntu 16.04) shutdown signal (e.g. power button clicked or runs out of battery). I have a python application that is always recording a video and I want to detect such signal so I close the recording properly before OS shutdown.

Comment: I asked a similar question on AU a while ago. Although the question was on log out, the answer also covers shutdown. http://askubuntu.com/questions/720380/how-can-i-run-a-local-command-to-run-a-script-on-just-before-log-out-of-a-un Also the answer mentions `python dbus` bindings.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When linux is shut down, all processes receive `SIGTERM` and if they won't  terminate after some timeout they are killed with `SIGKILL`. You can implement a signal handler to properly shutdown your application using the [`signal`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/signal.html) module. `systemd` (opposed to `upstart` in earlier Ubuntu verions) additionally sends `SIGHUP` on shutdown.

To verfiy that this actually works, I tried the following script on two Ubuntu VMs (12.04 and 16.04). The system waits for 10s (12.04/upstart) or 90s (16.04/systemd) before issuing `SIGKILL`.

The script ignores `SIGHUP` (which would otherwise also kill the process ungracefully) and will continuously print the time since the `SIGTERM` signal has been received to a text file.

**Note** I used `disown` (built-in bash command) to detach the process from the terminal.

```
python signaltest.py &
disown
```

**signaltest.py**

```
import signal
import time

stopped = False

out = open('log.txt', 'w')

def stop(sig, frame):
    global stopped
    stopped = True
    out.write('caught SIGTERM\n')
    out.flush()

def ignore(sig, frsma):
    out.write('ignoring signal %d\n' % sig)
    out.flush()

signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, stop)
signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, ignore)

while not stopped:
    out.write('running\n')
    out.flush()
    time.sleep(1)

stop_time = time.time()
while True:
    out.write('%.4fs after stop\n' % (time.time() - stop_time))
    out.flush()
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The last line printed into `log.txt` was:

```
10.1990s after stop
```

for 12.04 and

```
90.2448s after stop
```

for 16.04.

Comment: @JacobVlijm Did you actually try?

Comment: Nope, but the procedure is not interrupted if I am correct?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I tried with a Ubuntu VM and the shutdown is delayed by 10s if the process does not respond to `SIGTERM`

Comment: The question is if that is enough to save and close the video- application.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try this now and let you know - Yes, 10 seconds is enough for me to finalise all processes

Comment: I tried this with Ubuntu 16.04, the application is killed immediately, the procedure was not interrupted - Any idea what is going on? it looks like sigkill is fired too quickly

Comment: Did you disown the process from the executing shell?

Comment: @m.othman You are right, I took the wrong VM (12.04). But I think the timeout can be configured somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not yet an expert in Linux - when I use disown I get no such job. Also, I want to run your code as part of my program

Comment: @m.othman See my edit, but I'm afraid it's not about `disown`. I will research that later.

Comment: @m.othman Unfortunately, I did not get any further. I will probably asking a question on AskUbuntu.

Comment: @m.othman Hopefuly my last comment :) I found the solution (ignoring `SIGHUP`).

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175/execute-script-before-shutting-down)
Basically, put a script in /etc/rc0.d/ with the right name and execute a call to you python script.