# Is there a way for a python function/script to be executed when server is about to shutdown?

Tags: python, server, vps

I am working on a small project and would like to know if there is a way to execute a function/script if the server is about to shutdown, and if there is a way to hold it for a bit to complete the operations?
Thanks!

Edit:
I need this to work on a Ubuntu server.

Comment: there probably is a way, but it would depend on the server and the OS

Comment: This answer and implementation example is exactly what you want to do if you have a Linux server. [Python detect linux shutdown and run a command before shutting down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39275997/8840245)